# pull access denied repo does not exist or may require authorization: server message:insufficient_scope: authorization failed"host=registry-1.docker.io

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

My Docker container works perfectly locally and using the default context and the command "docker compose up". I'm trying to run my docker image on ECS in AWS following this guide - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/

I've followed all of the steps on the guide, after I've set the context to my new context (I've tried all 3 options) - after I run "docker compose up" I get the above error, here again for detail:

> INFO trying next host                              error="pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed" host=registry-1.docker.io
> pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

I've also set the user and added all of the permissions I can think of - image below

[image: permissions screenshot]

I've looked everywhere and I can't find traction, please help :)

The image is located on AWS ECS and Docker hub - I've tried both

Here is my Docker file:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
git \
curl \
libpng-dev \
libonig-dev \
libxml2-dev \
zip \
unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- -- 
install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath 
gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
# RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

USER $user
```

Comment: It's saying it can't find the docker image, so the details of what docker image you are using would be a key detail to include in your question.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB - updated my question with my Docker file. Just to confirm - The image is located on AWS ECS and Docker hub - I've tried both with no luck

Comment: That's a custom `Dockerfile`. The base image `php:7.4-fpm` may be located on those public docker repos, but this `Dockerfile` takes that base image and customizes it to create a new image. As per the tutorial you linked, you would need to create a private ECR repository, build this image locally, and push the image to the ECR repository, and then refer to **that** ECR image in your docker-compose file.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Mark! I'll give this a go on Monday - really appreciate the responses

Comment: @MarkB - thanks for helping again. I've checked and done the above you mentioned. In my buildspec.yml file I do have the correct URI - judging by your comment, I still need to change the image in the docker-compose file to the URI repo??